# Junit5: Injection of test extension is null on multiple tests

Tags: java, junit, junit5, spring-test, junit-jupiter

I am currently struggling with the Junit5, more precisely with Extensions and Parameterized Tests.

I have the following test directory structure:

```bash
.
└── daoimpl/
    └── src/
        ├── main/
        │   ├── java/
        │   │   └── ...
        │   └── resources/
        │       └── ...
        └── test/
            ├── java/
            │   └── com/
            │       └── foo/
            │           └── baz/
            │               ├── dao/
            │               │   ├── ADaoTest.java
            │               │   ├── Db1DaoTest.java
            │               │   └── Db2DaoTest.java
            │               └── resources/
            │                   ├── ATestResource.java
            │                   ├── Db1TestResource.java
            │                   └── Db2TestResource.java
            └── resources/
                └── ... // test context configurations
```

Where issued class declarations look as follows:

##### ATestResource.java

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public abstract class ATestResource implements AfterEachCallback, BeforeEachCallback {

    public List<String> schemas;

    public Map<String, List<Table>> tables;
}
```

##### Db1TestResource.java

```java
public final class Db1TestResource extends ATestResource {

    @Override
    public void afterEach(ExtensionContext context) {
        // NOP
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext context) {
        initSchemas();
        initTables();
    }
}
```

##### ADaoTest.java

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public abstract class ADaoTest {

    @Autowired
    DaoImpl dao;

    abstract ATestResource getResource();

    private Stream<Arguments> prepareSchemas() {
        return getResource().schemas.stream()
                .map(Arguments::of);
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("prepareSchemas")
    void getAllTablesForDefinedSchemasTest(String schema) {
        final List<Table> extractedTables = dao.getAllTablesBySchema(schema);
        assertTables(getResource().tables.get(schema), extractedTables);
    }
    // ...more tests
}
```

##### Db1DaoTest.java

```java
@ExtendWith(Db1TestResource.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/Db1DaoTest.xml" })
class Db1DaoTest extends ADaoTest {

    @RegisterExtension
    Db1TestResource testResource = new Db1TestResource();

    @Override
    Db1TestResource getResource() {
        return testResource;
    }
}
```

Basically, what I try to achieve is to have one test suite for multiple databases of different types. The `ADaoTest` should then be injected with the correct extension. Everything works fine if I loop manually through the test resource in the individual test scenario. However, this solution is not transparent, and if some of the test resources fail on regression, it is inconvenient for debugging as it requires looping through all schemas and tables.

If I try to use the `ParametrizedTest` of **Junit5** getResource in the method source is `null`. Furthermore, it is `null` after the first test run (time to time - nondeterministic behavior).

Does anyone know how to approach this so I can use Parametrized Tests without changing the class structure? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're running into is due to Jupiter's lifecycle: A parameterized test's parameters are resolved **before** a before-each callback is invoked.

The sporadic "success" of your tests stems from the combination of `@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)` and your double registration of `Db1TestResource` through `@ExtendWith` and `@RegisterExtension`. At least that's my informed guess.

One solution I can see is that you don't use a parameterised test but iterate over the tables in the test itself, e.g.

```java
@Test
void getAllTablesForDefinedSchemasTest() {
    getResource().schemas.forEach(schema -> {
        final List<Table> extractedTables = dao.getAllTablesBySchema(schema);
        assertTables(getResource().tables.get(schema), extractedTables);
    });
}
```

Alternatively, you could have a `ParameterResolver` to inject the list of tables as a parameter to the test method.

Update: Also, remove `@ExtendWith(Db1TestResource.class)` from `Db1DaoTest`. It's not needed, since you also use a `@RegisterExtension` field.

Comment: Thank you for your response. You see, the proposed solution is the one I want to avoid. I cannot understand why the first run fails with the `null` value of resource fields - it seems that the before each is not triggered. For all subsequent test, it works just fine.

Comment: The reason is as described. Jupiter’s lifecycle resolves the parameters before the call to before-each callback. The second test then uses the schema and tables from the FIRST call to beforeEach. You may not like it, but that’s how Jupiter’s lifecycle is.